# In struts 1.3 how to retrieve data from database and display it using DAO

Tags: java, database, struts, dao, struts-1

***M new to struts. I am making simple login page that display username and password by retrieving it from database. I m using DAO.
 I have LoginDAO.java, LoginAction.java and Displaydata.jsp pages.  ***

> **LoginDAO.java**

```
 public boolean login(String user,String pass) throws SQLException
     {
         Connection con = getConnection();

         Statement st;
        try {
            st = con.createStatement();



                  st.executeQuery("select * from login where Username='" + user + "' and Password='" + pass + "'");


                return true;
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

         return false;

     }
```

> **LoginAction.java**

```
public class LoginAction extends Action

{

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {



    DynaValidatorForm rf= (DynaValidatorForm) form;

 String username = rf.get("username").toString();
 String password = rf.get("password").toString();
 HttpSession session=request.getSession();
 session.setAttribute("user", username);

 Login dao= new Login();

 if(dao.login(username,password))
 {
      System.out.println("GOT");
        return mapping.findForward("success");}
    else
        {System.out.println("NOT");
    return mapping.findForward("failure");
        }
}
}
```

> and also what do i write in Dislpaydata.jsp to display username and password in it   dont want any java code in it. 
>   Thankyou

Comment: Formatting the code would be the great advantage to escape possible mistakes while reading this text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. Some time ago I built an application with Struts 1.x and MySql with login.

#### LoginAction

```
public ActionForward login( ... ) throws Exception {
    String forward;
    final String mail = PropertyUtils.getProperty(form, "mail");
    final String password = PropertyUtils.getProperty(form, "password");
    if (LoginService.getInstance().validate(mail, password)) {
        // Do something e.g. put name of user in session
        forward = SUCCESS;
    } else {
        forward = ERROR;
    }
    return mapping.findForward(forward);
}
```

#### LoginService

```
public boolean validate(final String mail, final String password) 
                                                        throws ServiceException {
    try {
        final boolean valid;

        // Validate null and empty

        // Validate with DB
        final UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
        final User user = dao.findByPk(mail);
        if (user == null) {
            valid = false;
        } else {
            if (password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                valid = true;
            } else {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        throw new ServiceException("Error validating user and password.", e);
    }
}
```

#### UserDAO

```
private static final String FIND_BY_PK_SQL 
                 = "SELECT mail, name, password, admin FROM user WHERE mail = ?";

public User findByPk(final String mail) throws DAOException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(FIND_BY_PK_SQL);
        ps.setString(1, mail); // PK, NOT NULL
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return fill(rs);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    } finally {
        // Close DB resources
    }
}

private User fill(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    final User user = new User();
    user.setMail(rs.getString("mail"));
    user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
    user.setAdmin(rs.getBoolean("admin"));
    return user;
}
```

In my case I have a table `user` with `mail` as a primary key. There are various forms.

More examples:

- [Building a Login Application](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/building-a-login-application/)
- [Struts Login Application Using Action Form Tutorial | DZone](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-login-page-example-1.html)
- [Creating a Email Login Web Application with Struts](http://r4r.co.in/java/struts/basic/tutorial/Example-6/)

---

e.g. For show the name of variable user in session scope from the database:

#### LoginAction

```
if (LoginService.getInstance().validate(mail, password)) {
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    final User user = UserService.getInstance().getUser(mail);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    forward = SUCCESS;
}
```

#### home.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>

Welcome,
<bean:write scope="session" name="user" property="name" filter="false" />
```

Comment: can you show me how to use sessions to display data after login.  M not able to understand how to use req.getAttribute("").

Comment: You can use [tag libraries](http://www.visualbuilder.com/jsp/struts/tutorial/using-struts-tag-libraries/) for avoids Java in your jsp's. My app use the struts tag libraries, perhaps switch to [JSTL](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/CatalogJSTL.htm) later.

Comment: Thanxs @paulvargas but i have done this i have created session while login and it is showing after login page. But now how would i use sessions to display all his information in jsp.Not able to use the already created session in another class named **RetrieveInfo.java** to display this data using another action class named **DisplayAction**.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. It depends on the flow of your application, as defined in the `struts-config.xml`. Retrieves user data, put them in some scope (`request` or `session`), and display it in the appropriate JSP.

Comment: hey thanks for ur hellp i am finaly able o retrieve my info :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
 <form action="action" method="post" id="formDemo" name="MyForm">

  <div id="header">
   <h2 style="color: red;">Training</h2>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <div id="center" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 220px;">
   <table align="center">

    <tr>
     <th colspan="2"><h1 style="color: BLUE;">LOGIN</h1></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <th colspan="2"><h5 id="error" style="color: red;"></h5></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>UserID:</td>
     <td><input type="text" size="40" name="UserId" maxlength="8"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type="text" size="40" name="Password" maxlength="8"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
      value="Login"> <input type="button" id="reset"
      value="Clear"></td>
    </tr>

   </table>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div id="footer">
   <label>Copy right@ 2000-2008 FUJINET, All Rights Reserved.</label>

  </div>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
  // Form validation code will come here.

  function validate() {

   if (document.MyForm.UserId.value === ""
     || document.MyForm.UserId.value === null) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please insert userId";

    return false;
   }

   if (document.MyForm.Password.value === ""
     || document.MyForm.Password.value === null) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please insert password";

    return false;

   }
   return (true);
  }
  $("#reset").click(function(event) {
   document.MyForm.UserId.value = "";
   document.MyForm.Password.value = "";
   document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  });
  $("#formDemo").submit(function(event){
   return validate();
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't just post code as an answer, explain what your code does and how it answers the question.